Не работает laravel проект с typesense
Проект и typesense запущены в одном контейнере докера
При попытке вызова метода "Film::search($request->name)->get()->toArray()" происходит ошибка
cURL error 7: Failed to connect to localhost port 8108 after 0 ms: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://localhost:8108/collections/films

При вызове "curl http://localhost:8108/health" приходит ответ ok true
Вот docker-compose
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.3
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
        image: sail-8.3/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
            - '${VITE_PORT:-5173}:${VITE_PORT:-5173}'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
            IGNITION_LOCAL_SITES_PATH: '${PWD}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mysql
            - redis
            - meilisearch
            - mailpit
            - selenium
    mysql:
        image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - mysqladmin
                - ping
                - '-p${DB_PASSWORD}'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    redis:
        image: 'redis:alpine'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_REDIS_PORT:-6379}:6379'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-redis:/data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - redis-cli
                - ping
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    meilisearch:
        image: 'getmeili/meilisearch:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MEILISEARCH_PORT:-7700}:7700'
        environment:
            MEILI_NO_ANALYTICS: '${MEILISEARCH_NO_ANALYTICS:-false}'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-meilisearch:/meili_data'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test:
                - CMD
                - wget
                - '--no-verbose'
                - '--spider'
                - 'http://localhost:7700/health'
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
    mailpit:
        image: 'axllent/mailpit:latest'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_MAILPIT_PORT:-1025}:1025'
            - '${FORWARD_MAILPIT_DASHBOARD_PORT:-8025}:8025'
        networks:
            - sail
    selenium:
        image: seleniarm/standalone-chromium
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        volumes:
            - '/dev/shm:/dev/shm'
        networks:
            - sail
    typesense:
        image: typesense/typesense:26.0
        restart: on-failure
        ports:
            - "8108:8108"
        volumes:
            - ./typesense-data:/data
        command: '--data-dir /data --api-key=xyz --enable-cors'
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mysql:
        driver: local
    sail-redis:
        driver: local
    sail-meilisearch:
        driver: local

Если честно, плохо понимаю докер и не знаю в чем может быть проблема.
Они вроде в одном контейнере запущены, оба работают
Пробовал менять localhost на 127.0.0.1
